# Tagline showing instead of meta description!

Tags: seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I have a website called charlieandco.co.nz based on Wordpress. I installed the Yoast SEO plugin to set the SEO title and meta description of the website pages. However, after 1 week of changing, Google doesn't show that meta description but instead shows Tagline and some other info. This appears on every page. The website is attached with google console with sitemap indexed.

Image of the website on a bing search engine.

[image: website appearing on bing]

Image of the website on a Google search engine.

[image: website on a Google search engine]

Comment: If you look at your homepage you can see you've got two meta descriptions: the tagline first, then the full text you're seeing in Bing. The second one is after the Yoast comment so it looks like something else is generating the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have two meta description tags on your site. If you view the source or use an inspector, you can see the duplicates for yourself.

As to where they're coming from, there are two possibilities. Themes and plugins can both output the final rendered code of your site. So, to figure out where the extra meta description tag is coming from, it would be fastest to switch to a default theme and see if that removes it. If not, you can switch back to your theme, and go through plugins one by one to determine which one is inserting the tag.

Comment: I talked with my designer about this. Said it was fixed. I have inspected the page and saw only the meta tag generated by Yoast SEO. Let's see how Google index it now.